# Javascript filering not working when used with string of array

Tags: lightning, javascript, array

0

I am trying to filter a javascript array (json array) with the string array, and set it back in itself.

I am using this code`

```
var statusFilters = component.get("v.statusFilters");
console.log('statusFilters--->'+statusFilters);
var allRecords = JSON.stringify(component.get("v.empWrapperList"));
console.log('allRecords--->'+allRecords);
var filteredRecords = allRecords.filter(rec => rec.Status__c == statusFilters);
console.log(filteredRecords);
component.set("v.empWrapperList",filteredRecords);`
```

Here statusFilter is a string Array and allRecords is a json array.

Here are the logs from console.

statusFilters--->Paid ClaimsDemo.js:119 allRecords--->[{"Id":"a1V2x000001K29pEAC","Name":"CL-0000004","Member__c":"0032x000004bgAkAAI","Date_of_Service__c":"2020-06-25","Provider__c":"a112x000003VXGEAA4","Status__c":"Void"},{"Id":"a1V2x000001K14OEAS","Name":"CL-0000003","Member__c":"0032x000004bgAkAAI","Billed__c":22,"Date_of_Service__c":"2015-09-15","Provider__c":"a112x000003VXGEAA4","Status__c":"Denied"},{"Id":"a1V2x000001K14JEAS","Name":"CL-0000002","Member__c":"0032x000004bgAkAAI","Billed__c":22,"Date_of_Service__c":"2019-10-16","Provider__c":"a112x000003VXGEAA4","Status__c":"Rejected"},{"Id":"a1V2x000001K14EEAS","Name":"CL-0000001","Member__c":"0032x000004bgAkAAI","Billed__c":22,"Date_of_Service__c":"2020-06-04","Provider__c":"a112x000003VXGEAA4","Status__c":"Paid"}]

Actually it is unable to execute this line var filteredRecords = allRecords.filter(rec => rec.Status__c == statusFilters);

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this, such as:

```
var filteredRecords = allRecords.filter(
  rec => statusFilters.find(
    status => status === rec.Status__c
  )
);
```

Or:

```
var filteredRecords = allRecords.filter(rec => statusFilters.indexOf(rec.Status__c) > -1);
```

Or:

```
var filteredRecords = allRecords.filter(
  rec => statusFilters.some(
    status => status === rec.Status__c
  )
);
```

The main point is that == would require that the selected status is equal to all the filters, which will never be true, even if only one value is selected.